# Selecting values from different Dates R

Tags: r, date, aggregate, average

I have a quick question using the following dataframe.

```
x <- c("2012-01-01","2012-01-01","2012-01-01","2012-01-02","2012-01-02","2012-01-03","2012-01-03")

y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

data.frame(x,y)
```

Now i want to take the average of y for each date specified in x, how can i do do that? I have difficulty because the amount of observations is different for each date
Many thanks

Comment: take a look at the functions `aggregate`, `by` or `tapply`. Just go through the example in the help page by doing `?by` for example

Comment: Number of elements in x and y are not same. Aren't you getting an error when calling data.frame(x, y)?

Comment: Yeah sorry, it was a fast example, edited now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you can use the `aggregate` function like so:

```
df <- data.frame(x,y)
aggregate( y ~ x , df , mean )
#           x   y
#1 2012-01-01 2.0
#2 2012-01-02 4.5
#3 2012-01-03 6.5
```

But that is one of the *many* ways you could do this and the *best* was will depend on things like structure of your real data.

A data.table solution could be:

```
require( data.table )
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[, mean(y) , by = x ]
#           x  V1
#1: 2012-01-01 2.0
#2: 2012-01-02 4.5
#3: 2012-01-03 6.5
```

Or if you want to add a new column that contains the mean you could use:

```
DT[ , "Mean" := mean(y) , by = x ]
```